# How to use a combination of parametrised unit test and mocking

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I want to mock an internal `class MorphologyTaggerService()` which calls external package, used within my `method get_case_nom`, and use parametrised test.

I tried:

```
@parameterized.expand([
        ["Petr", "Petr"],
        ["Karlovi", "Karel"],
        ["babičce Martě", "babička Marta"],
        ["jemu", "On"],
        ["ČEZu", "ČEZ"],
    ])
def test_getCaseNom(input, output):
    mts = mock(MorphologyTaggerService())
    when(mts).get_case_nom(input).thenReturn(output)

    assert_that(mts.get_case_nom(input)).is_equal_to(output)
```

Comment: And I take it that _didn't_ work? Give a [mre].

Comment: Side note: `input` is a keyword in python, you *can* use it as a variable name, but it would be better not to